# How to solve missing css Issue in Angular Java app on app server

Tags: java, angular, single-sign-on

I have angular7 + java web application.

I have configured SSO login for it on a apache tomcat server. Only authentication is done from SSO , Authorization is done using a users table in the application database.

This setup works fine on my local system, Authorization happens for Valid user & invalid user is redirected to access denied page using a custom interceptor typescript code in angular.

But when I deploy this on the server in face an issue. Valid users are logged in perfectly using SSO authentication & application Authorization. 
But when I hit the application from an invalid user, it shows the login page with no css applied, instead of the access denied page which it is supposed to redirect to. 
In the network I see 500 error for the `style.css` file and a 403 forbidden error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem at your server end, debug your code and fix accordingly.

Comment: Should be as a comment! and [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) of the question that you will ask!

Comment: for missing css issue check for selectors in your typescript file . Whether you have mentioned css file correctly or not

Answer (score 0):

I think I also faced the same problem when I was updating my data in S3 bucket in AWS, 
You just need to fill all empty .css file with something like this :

```
/* Nothing here*/
```